# Access Windows Sound?

Tags: c++, windows, audio

I'd like to know a couple of things:
1.) How do I check how much noise / how loud all noises coming from the computer (Windows) are?
2.) How do I adjust the Windows volume?

Thanks!

Comment: Hmm, maybe [try this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd370839(v=vs.85).aspx)...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

waveOutGetVolume: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd743864(VS.85).aspx
waveOutSetVolume: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd743874(v=VS.85).aspx

See this knowledgebase article: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/139098